# Microsoft Graph API doesn't return search results

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

We have created tenant and around 1200 groups under it and have been trying to search for documents through Graph API.

Here's the query: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/drive/root/search(q='c')
We are sure that there is document with 'c' in name uploaded to the group.

This query was returning results when there was couple of groups created on the tenant. After around 800 groups created, Graph API started to return results very slowly, and on 1200 stopped to return any results.

Is there any throttle or there are some issues on Graph API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your requests are being throttled. If you are seeing `HTTP 429` responses that is the case.

You could consider using the graph batch API to issue multiple queries at the same time vs. doing each one individually, this will help with not being throttled also.

[Combine multiple requests in one HTTP call using JSON batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response.

The solution you proposed is not acceptable for us since as I wrote in the question, we are facing this issue even we try to query just one group at the time: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/drive/root/search(q='c')

Any other solution?

Thanks